# iPad/iPhone please stop parsing telephone number on my site

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad, browser

my iPad is recognizing telephone numbers on my site and breaks the layout. How I can stop that?

The site is here: [my site](http://mihalko.eu)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can let the DOM know not to code `tel` functionality into the content encoding with the following meta tag:

```
<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: values of β may give rise to dom!

Answer (score 0):

If you do want this functionality anywhere on the site but numbers at specific places are breaking the layout, you can wrap those numbers in `<a>` tags, even without `href`, and so parsers won't turn them into clickable links.